# Prove for any sets, $A, B, C$ we have $(A \cup B) \setminus C \subseteq (A \setminus (B \cup C)) \cup (B \setminus (A \cap C))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I've drawn out a Venn Diagram to see how it is a subset but I'm unsure how to write this proof.
I was given a hint that said, given $x \in A \cup B$ then it would be easiest to consider cases

Case 1: $x \in B$

Case 2: $x \not \in B$.

Considering case 1, I would have that if $x \in B$, then $x \not \in A$ or $x \not \in C$

Considering case 2, then if $x \not \in B$, then $x \in A$ and $x \not \in C$.

Is this the right way of thinking through this problem? Overall, I am very confused on how to start this problem.

Comment: Welcome. Please expand on your thought process. It's easy for me to write an answer but it's very hard for me to write an answer that addresses your concerns in a helpful way. There are various "how to ask a good question" links around and about. Please edit appropriately so that you can receive proper help

Answer (score 0):

$(A\setminus (B\cup C))\;\cup \;(B\setminus (A\cup C))$

$\supseteq$

$(A\setminus  C)\;\cup \;(B\setminus  C)$

$=$

$(A\cup B)\;\setminus C.$

Comment: Indeed this can be adapted to the proof in the form "x is in LHS implies x is in RHS" by using the last inequality.

Comment: Why does changing (A∪B)∖C to (A∖C)∪(B∖C) get you to that conclusion?

Comment: For any propositions $P,Q,R$ we have $\forall x\,[(P\lor Q)\land R] \iff \forall x\, [(P\land R)\lor (Q\land R)].$ Let $P$ be $x\in A.$ Let $Q$ be $x\in B.$ Let $R$ be $x\not\in C.$